# Android - Как изменить XML-файл?

Tags: xml, android, java

Здравствуйте! Я храню настройки своего приложения в .xml-файле на SD-карте.
В приложении есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую некоторые значения в этом xml должны замениться на "0".
Можно ли как-нибудь быстро изменить значения, не прибегая к банальному `.replace(...)`?

Структура файла

---

```
<map>
    <int name="pl_size" value="41" />
    <int name="new_task_at" value="6" />
    <int name="grafon" value="2" />
    <double name="sound_ch_left" value="40.999998" />
    <int name="mixer_en" value="1" />
</map>
```

---

**UPDATE** Набросал код, но он выкидывает NPE на строке...

```
Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);
```

...хотя всё (пути/теги) введено правильно.

---

```
protected void ReplaceXMLTagValues(String path, String tag, String new_value)
{
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

        Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);
        nodes.setNodeValue(new_value);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Comment: А не проще воспользоваться PreferenceManager?

Comment: Я им и так пользуюсь, просто раньше возникла необходимость хранить некоторые настройки на sdcard.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать XMLPullParser. Что касательно вашей задачи. Неужели вы не умеете пользоваться debug инструментом что бы понять почему у вас NPE? Это намного легче чем создать пост на хешкоде.

Comment: Вообще-то я создаю пост на ХК не из-за NPE.

Answer (score 2):

Я не уверен, что на андроиде есть встроенный способ редактирования XML. Но можно подключить сторонние java библиотеки для работы с XML. Например simple xml или jaxb. Первый лично мне больше нравится, кроме того он очень легкий (и для понимания, и в плане занимаемого места). А если настройки совсем простые, так зачем вообще xml? Есть ini или csv.